# How do i put my registration form in tables?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms

I need to divide my registration form in 3 tabular blocks , i do have knowledge of html but html.erb seems to work in a different way . Can anyone throw some light on how i should go on doing this ?

```
 <fieldset>
  <table>
     <tr>
     <ol>
        <li>
          <td>   <%= f.required_label :first_name %> </td>
          <td>   <%= f.text_field :first_name %>&nbsp;</td>
       </li>
     </ol>
     </tr>
  </table>
  </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write ruby code anywhere in **.erb** file,
If you write any code between this `<%= %>` that means it will printed on the page and you can use `<% %>` symbol for variables and loops.
And check out the guides to understand layout
[Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand the problem properly but this code should work. As I know there is no `required_label` Form helper method.

```
<fieldset>
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <ol>
        <li>
          <td><%= f.label :first_name %></td>
          <td><%= f.text_field :first_name, required: true %></td>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </tr>
  </table>
<% end %>
</fieldset>
```